# XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException Error in Spring Maven project

Tags: java

I created new Maven project in spring framework, but i am getting error while running project.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 37 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 9; cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'bean' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

Below is my spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">


<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<!--<annotation-driven />-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.mvc" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean> class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">


<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<!--<annotation-driven />-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.mvc" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bean tag is not correct, you close it prematurely (extra `>`):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
```

See [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s05.html) in *16.5.2 Chaining ViewResolvers*